# Datatype mismatch in criteria expression on update

Tags: vb.net

I am getting a datatype mismatch in criteria expression error on updating the MS Access database table. I am aware of the single quotes on 'string' data type as I have check similar questions about this error. Can it be because of the image which is part of the query?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
btnSave.Click
    Try
con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
            Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(pbMyImage.Image)
            bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Dim data As Byte() = ms.GetBuffer()
            Dim p As New OleDbParameter("@image", OleDbType.VarBinary)
            p.Value = data
            Dim cb As String = "Update Members set IDPassNum = @IDPass and Firstname = @Fname and Lastname = @LName and Gender = @gender and Contact1 = @contact1 and Contact2 = @contact2 and City = @city and Address = @address and DoB = @dob and EmailID = @email and DOJ = @doj and Designation =@design and Status =@status and Photo = @image where TKBSNum = @tkbsnum"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(cb)
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IDPass", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fname", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@contact1", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@contact2", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@doj", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@design", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@tkbsnum", OleDbType.Char)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated member details", " TKBS 
 Member Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            con.Close()
 End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR5", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
 MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
 End Sub
```

Here is the database structure:

[image: [enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dKeJ.png)

Comment: The parameter '@Image' doesn't look quite right to me, shouldn't it be something like -  and Photo = @image

Comment: And you really should be using parameterised queries in general.

Comment: Debug.print cb when you've built it, then paste it into whatever the equivalent is in Access for SSMS. And, what Mahendran said.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Benno, it worked. I dont know how I didn't notice that. Mahendranm, I shall consider that. Thank you.

Comment: Never concat values into a query string for SQL.  Doing so is dangerous and leads to exactly that kind of error as well as tedious code like that.  Always use SQL parameters.  Also, `GetBuffer` is the wring thing to use - it can bloat the size of the data saved by a great deal.

Comment: @Plutonix, I have edited my post and used the parameters as suggested. The applications runs but on saving what ever have been edited, the first error I got was "object reference not set to instance of an object". I clicked OK and continues and that error just didn't repeat. The very one I am getting now is this: "Parameter IDPass has no default value"